# Android Activity Life Cycle Methods

Tags: android, methods, dialog, alert, lifecycle

I'm a Newbie to android, I'm Developing a Hangman Application in android my application works fine but only confusion I'm facing is whenever back button is triggered game should not be exited.

I have provided an Alert dialog in the on Pause method to the user weather to exit or resume the game if back button is pressed.But its not working can anyone please say me how to write the Activity cycle methods while developing the games.

Comment: Why not just serialize the game's state, let the user do what they want, then bring the game back to it's previous state when the user resumes?

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't be adding any dialogs to the back key or disable its behavior. That would just irritate your users.

If you still insist, override `onBackPressed()` in your activity and don't call `super.onBackPressed()` there. Call `finish()` in case you want to exit from the activity.

Required further reading: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch when the back button is pressed. Use this-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) 
    {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                     //Write your code here
    }
}
```

But I don't think it will work in Virtual buttons like in Nexus 5 though, But give it a try.